# Jest mocking of the readOnly function from dependant file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

**mainClass.js**

```
import { GetData } from './childClass';

export class MainClass {
  static async execute() {
    const response = GetData();
    return response;
  }
}
```

**childClass.js**

```
class response {
  constructor({ data }) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

export async function GetData() {
  return new response(data);
}
```

Here I'm trying to test this mainClass.js **execute** function using jest. And for testing I want to mock the **GetData** function which is part of childClass file. But here is the thing that I can't directly mock that function because GetData is **read-only**. I can't change that function property to read and write. So I want a way to mock this GetData function in any way.

Tried things

```
1)
beforeAll(() => {
  jest.mock('./childClass', () => ({
    GetData: jest.fn()
 }));
});

2)
beforeAll(() => {
  mockFunctionData = jest.spyOn(MainClass, 'GetData').mockReturnValue({});
});
```

None of are working. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I personally prefer `spyOn`, so I'll answer with it.

When you do `jest.spyOn(MainClass, 'GetData')`, you are targeting the wrong thing. You want to mock the `GetData` function in `childClass.js`.

So you need to spy on the object which contains it: not `MainClass`.

And in your case, the object is a module (i.e. a file). So you have to import the module as a whole, then spy on it:

```js
import * as childClassModule from './childClass'

// Note: `beforeAll()` won't work in some cases, depending on your Jest configuration.
// So it's better to use `beforeEach()` in this case.
beforeEach(() => {
  // Since your `GetData` function is async, you have to use `mockResolvedValue()`.
  jest.spyOn(childClassModule, 'GetData').mockResolvedValue({data: 'hello world'})
})

test('example', async () => {
  const result = await MainClass.execute()
  expect(result).toStrictEqual({data: 'hello world'})
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Drarig29. It's working for me. Actually I new to this jest unit testing. Again thank you dude for helping.